# How to handle streaming RDD output with bytestring from java code in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-2.0

I have a streaming pipeline wherein the nested json format data is fed to Cloud PubSub. Data is then fetched as streams using Spark Streaming
The streams(rdd) data when printed to check the schema gives `_corrupted_record : String`.

The above custom receiver code is in Java.
The output RDD id then handled using Pyspark .

On printing the rdd found it is prefixed with b'(byte string format).

```
(b'{"_id": {"_data": "abv1"}, "operationType": "insert", "clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1622466457, "i": 393}}, "fullDocument": {"_id": "nhmm7779", "uid": "5FZ", "cb": {"key1": "jk8", "user_id": "jk-3"}, "cmp": {"c": "Organic"}, "ts": 1622466405939.0, "cd": {"$date": 1622466457352}, "d": "2021:5:31",  "sg": {"key5": "hj", "key6": "TV Menu", "key7": "NA"}, "s": 0, "dur": 0}, "ns": {"db": "database", "coll": "abnv55666"}, "documentKey": {"_id": "nhmm7779"}}', 
b'{"_id": {"_data": "bhg4"}, "operationType": "insert", "clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1622466480, "i": 542}}, "fullDocument": {"_id": "nm1", "uid": "qS", "cb": {"key1": "jku", "user_id": "ty6"}, "cmp": {"c": "Organic"}, "ts": 1622466434999.0, "cd": {"$date": 1622466480445}, "d": "2021:5:31", "sg": {"key5": "bn", "key6": 0, "key7": "val2"}, "s": 0, "dur": 0}, "ns": {"db": "database", "coll": "bvgh678"}, "documentKey": {"_id": "nm1"}}')
```

How to handle this rdd in pyspark wherein the records can be saved as 2 different rows and not 1.

Things I tried:

On further debugging figured out that it is more serialization issue when calling java code from Pyspark. hence changed the subject of the issue.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue.

1) Once the Dstream is accessed using pyspark, used flatMap( lambda x: x) to flatten the records in dstream rdd.
2) Further since the input source of json schema used json.loads() to parse a valid JSON string and convert it into a Python Dictionary
3) Last saved this data to BQ